# Gitattributes behaving weirdly for line endings (with gitlab)

Tags: git, gitlab, line-endings, gitattributes

I have many repositories in GitLab with Maven/Java projects in them.
A new colleague recently joined our team and we decided to add a `.gitattributes` file to the repositories to lessen the configuration burden when setting up a new developer computer.

Here a simplified version of our `.gitattributes`

```
* text=auto eol=lf

*.bat text eol=crlf
*.cmd text eol=crlf
```

This works well for local checkouts, but if we download the files directly from Gitlab it returns the files with linux endings which causes issues for some of our workflows that uses these downloads instead of git checkouts.

Is that a GitLab issue or a configuration issue on our side?
How can I avoid running into the same problem again, when I run `git add . --renormalize` again?

Comment: "*…if we download the files directly from Gitlab it returns the files with linux endings which causes issues for some of our workflows that uses these downloads instead of git checkouts.*" Then don't do that; always clone/checkout instead of direct downloads. "*Is that a GitLab issue or a configuration issue on our side?*" Neither; Git hostings (GitHub, GitLab, etc., all of them) ignore `.gitattributes` to not allow committed files to dictate their configuration; security measure.